# Why does my script stop running after calling XMLHttpRequest.send()?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to get a handle on how the `XMLHttpRequest()` object works.

If I remove `xhr.send()`, `"hi"` will display.  But nothing displays when it is present.  I really want to write the `xhr.status` to the screen, but first I need to know why the script doesn't finish executing, even though the remainder does not depend on the response after `xhr.send()`.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Playground</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <script>
                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.open("GET","http://www.google.com",false);
                xhr.send();
                document.write("hi");
            </script>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are setting the async parameter in `open` to false, so it's going to lock until that completes.

Comment: How long should I wait before I assume it is not going to complete? I've waited over a minute...seems like it should be completing faster than that, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`XMLHttpRequest` can be used as synchronous and asynchronous, third parameter passed into the function sets this mode. Passing `false` means set to synchronous e.g wait till call finished

Change it to:

```
 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.open("GET","http://www.google.com",true);
                xhr.send();
                document.write("hi");
```

and it should write out `"hi"` or you can remove third parameter completely it defaults to asynchronous

```
 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    xhr.open("GET","http://www.google.com");
                    xhr.send();
                    document.write("hi");
```

Comment: Yes, you're quite right. If set to async then the AJAX call still throws an error, but the next line still executes.

Comment: OK, that is helpful...why doesn't the script continue once there is a response?

Comment: @David you do not get response from google, so it fails and never continues. To test change url to one that gives proper AJAX response.

Answer (score 0):

You can't make an XHR request to `http://www.google.com` due to it being a different origin. If you open the development console you'll likely see an error such as this:

```
Uncaught NetworkError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': 
Failed to load 'http://www.google.com/'.
```

In order to make an AJAX request, the requested domain, port and protocol must match the origin.

Since this line of your script is throwing an error, and the call is set to *not be asynchronous (as stated by LIUFA)*, the next line will not be executed.

Comment: OK, what would I need to change so that I can print out xhr.status with the response of xhr.send()?